# XML/AJAX - get value of a specific child element

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

i got a problem with ajax and xml. i have a xml file, which covers the status of several buttons. so now in my webpage i wand to check the actual status of each button. here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<btn_status>
    <btn1>
        <titel>Button 1</titel>
        <status>inactive</status>
    </btn1>

    <btn2>
        <titel>Button 2</titel>
        <status>active</status>
    </btn2>

</btn_status>
```

my ajax script looks like this.

```
document.write("<p>Status der Buttons</p>");
document.write("<table border='1'>");
var xmlContent=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("btn1");
for (i=0;i<xmlContent.length;i++)
  {
  document.write("<tr><td>");
  document.write(xmlContent[i].getElementsByTagName("titel")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(xmlContent[i].getElementsByTagName("status")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue );
    if(btnStatus1=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("status")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue == 'active'){
      document.write("<img src='Normal.png' />");
    }
      else  // ie5/6
  {
      document.write("<img src='error.png' />");
  }
    document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
```

the problem is now, that the if/else only covers the status of btn1 not the others and now i dont know how to questioned the status of btn2 and the following ones. something like

```
btnStatus2=btn2.status...
```

anyone got an idea :/

Answer (score 0):

sry solved it myself, just had to cound torwards the child elements...

```
if(btnStatus2=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("status")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue == 'active'){
      document.write("<img src='Normal.png' />");
    }
      else  // ie5/6
  {
      document.write("<img src='error.png' />");
  }
    document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
```

and for the third entry:

```
var xmlContent=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("btn3");
for (i=0;i<xmlContent.length;i++)
  {
  document.write("<tr><td>");
  document.write(xmlContent[i].getElementsByTagName("titel")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(xmlContent[i].getElementsByTagName("status")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue );
    if(btnStatus3=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("status")[2].childNodes[0].nodeValue == 'active'){
      document.write("<img src='Normal.png' />");
    }
      else  // ie5/6
  {
      document.write("<img src='error.png' />");
  }
    document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
```